# Label on QToolBar, possible?

Tags: qt, c++11, user-interface, qt5, statusbar

Is is possible to have labels in a `QToolBar`? Something like the green text I draw on top of the app screenshot.

I would like to have a set of actions in a toolbar, all them retated to some a system. Then another toolbar with another set of actions related to another system. So each toolbar would have a label named accordingly to the specific system.

[image]

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QMainWindow *w = new QMainWindow;

QToolBar *barA = new QToolBar;
barA->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);

QAction *actOnA = new QAction("OnA");
actOnA->setIcon(QIcon("../../../on.png"));
barA->addAction(actOnA);
QAction *actOffA = new QAction("OffA");
actOffA->setIcon(QIcon("../../../off.png"));
barA->addAction(actOffA);
w->addToolBar(barA);

QToolBar *barB = new QToolBar;
barB->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);

QAction *actOnB = new QAction("OnB");
actOnB->setIcon(QIcon("../../../on.png"));
barB->addAction(actOnB);
QAction *actOffB = new QAction("OffB");
actOffB->setIcon(QIcon("../../../off.png"));
barB->addAction(actOffB);
w->addToolBar(barB);

w->show();
return a.exec();
```

I think I saw similar labels in a Microsoft MFC project.

Comment: How about you design a custom widget that contains both on/off icons and the subcaption. Then you can add the widget to a toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you need to create your custom widget first and then do:

```
ui->statusBar->addWidget(MY_CUSTOM_WIDGEt);
```

e.g.

```
auto b = new QPushButton(this);
b->setText("hello");
connect(b, &QPushButton::clicked, [](){qDebug()<< "ok...";});
ui->statusBar->addWidget(b);
```